# Python Dynamic Object Generation Confusion

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I'm writing a Python script that takes a directory, and for each file of a specific type in that directory, creates a dictionary or custom object.

I feel like an idiot, but when I get to the part of actually creating the dictionary..I'm confused on how to instantiate and track the dynamic objects.

```
#Pseudocode
for each conf file in given directory:
    x = customObject('filename') # variable name fail
    track_list.append(customObject('filename')) # this seems weird
```

Should I be creating these objects and adding them to a list? How do people usually do this? I feel like I'm trying to write code that writes more code?

Comment: Clarification needed: By "creates a dictionary or custom object" did you mean "creates a dictionary **of** custom object (**s**)" by any chance? And by "for each file of a specific type in that directory, creates" do you mean creates a separate one (dictionary) for each different type of file found?

Answer (score 2):

```
track_list = [custom_object(filename) for filename in directory]
```

where directory is a list of the file names you care about is a pretty common pattern. If you want a dictionary with file names for keywords, you can do this:

```
custom_dict = dict((filename, custom_object(filename)) for filename in directory)
```

Answer (score 1):

@nmichaels answer is the cleanest and most Pythonic way to do it. An even shorter way would be:

```
track_list = map(customObject, directory)
```

EDIT: oh I see you wanted a dictionary, even though your pseudocode makes a list. You can do this:

```
result = dict((filename, customObject(filename)) for filename in directory)
```

Explanation: `dict` takes an object that when iterated over yields tuples and turns them into a dictionary, e.g.

```
>>> dict([('hey', 3), ('food', 4), ('haxhax', 6)])
{'food': 4, 'haxhax': 6, 'hey': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_objects = {name:customObject(name) for name in dir if isMyType(name)}
```

Comment: Hey, it does. 2.7 came out after 3, but now I have a reason to upgrade to it! Go aptitude, go.